# Having issue using shuffle with array and mysql query

Tags: php, arrays

I' am running into a problem where an array is not being able to shuffle. I want the array to randomized for each page loads. I followed the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) but something still wrong over here

**Error Message**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\snppets\sidebar.php on line 65
```

**This is the code that gets the friends list, makes the sting into array, counts the array and shuffles it.**

```
$friends = get_friends_IDS($profile_id);
$friends = make_string_to_ARRAY($friends);
$friends_count = count($friends);
$friends = shuffle($friends);
```

**This is the code that is in line 65**

```
<?php
foreach($friends as $id){
        $sql = "SELECT profile_id, profile_photo, profile_username, profile_name FROM profile WHERE profile_id='$id' LIMIT 1";
            $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
            $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
                if($db->NUM_ROWS() > 0){
                    foreach($rows as $row){
                        $friends_profile_id = $row->profile_id;
                        $friends_profile_photo = $row->profile_photo;
                        $friends_profile_username = $row->profile_username;
                        $friends_profile_name = $row->profile_name;
                    }
            }
}
?>
```

**This function gets the friends list from the database**

```
function get_friends_IDS($profile_id){
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT profile_id, profile_friends FROM profile WHERE profile_id='$profile_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
        if($db->NUM_ROWS()){
        foreach($db->FETCH_OBJECT() as $row){
          return $row->profile_friends;
        }
      }
    }
```

**This is the function makes a string into array**

```
function make_string_to_ARRAY($array){
  $array = explode(',', $array);
  return $array;
}
```

**When I remove the shuffle then it works fine...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shuffle()](https://www.php.net/shuffle) returns boolean value.

So `$friends = shuffle($friends);` makes $friends as a boolean variable.

just use `shuffle($friends);` to shuffle it

Comment: Upvote. for this catch.

Comment: You are awesome man, thanks! My fault was that I made the  shuffle($friends); into local variable.

Comment: Sure will after 6 minutes...